# How best to time tag stderr output

Tags: raspbian

I'm running an embedded application on a RPI. I am planning to have a script restart it if it crashes. But I'd like to see the crash info. So I see how to redirect stderr to a file to append the latest crash details but I would like to add a time tag for each crash situation. 1) Is there an easy way to do this? I wrote a simple python program to write out a time tag followed by reading from stdin and echoing the data out. 2) How can I redirect just the stderr output to my program? I tried the following command line but it doesn't work. Not sure proper way to do this.

**sudo python3 TestRedirect.py 2> | sudo python3 TimeTagErrors.py**

Maybe the answer to question 1 will make question 2 not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you should simply:

1. add **exception handling** in your Python program - if you aren't already you should
2. log exceptions to a file, for this use the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module. See here: [Basic Logging Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) and here: [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook) for an intro

That should be enough.

To have the script restart upon failure: one way is to write your own **systemd service**.

If you really want to **capture console output** I would suggest running your script in a [GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) session. Then you easily [capture](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Logging) all console output to a log file.

Comment: A systemd service will log output to syslog with a timestamp.

Comment: It's a bit of a misnomer to refer to capturing "console output" here.  It's output that *would go to* a console if the script were run from the command line (ie, in a console context).  The script/program doesn't really do that itself; it simply writes to stdout/stderr (which are intrinsic properties of a running process), and this is captured by the console.  Point being, using `screen` would indeed allow you to run the program in a console context (screen playing the console) but this is neither necessary nor generally desirable (unless the output is formatted specially for a console).